# ¿Como crear un método genérico que me permita ejecutar cualquier Stored Procedure con parametros en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un proyecto en C# con sql server 2017 y tengo la clase DAO_Socio, que se encarga de armar los objetos que se comunican con la Base de datos:

```
public Inscripcion getSociosPorNombre(string nombreSocio)
            {   
                string sp, columna, parametro;
                sp = "sp_listar_socios_por_nombre";
                columna = "@nombre";
                parametro = nombreSocio;
                DataTable tabla = getSociosPorNombre(sp,columna,parametro);
                Inscripcion inscripcion = new Inscripcion();
                foreach (DataRow fila in tabla.Rows)
                {
                    inscripcion = mapper(fila);              
                }
                return inscripcion;
            }
```

A su vez, la clase DBHelper es la encargada de comunicarse con la base de datos.

El siguiente metodo me permite traer una tabla desde la base de datos, a traves de un stored procedure:

```
public DataTable getSociosPorNombre(string storedProcedure, string nombreColumna, string parametro)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            
            try
            {
                cnn.ConnectionString = string_conexion;
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = cnn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(nombreColumna,parametro);
                tabla.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                return tabla;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("EXPLOTO EL HELPER", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                throw (ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.CloseConnection(cnn);
            }
        }
```

El problema de este método es que solo le puedo pasar un solo parámetro. Como hago para que el método ejecute cualquier tipo de SP, con cualquier cantidad de parámetros sin tener que especificar el nombre de la columna y el valor que le paso.

Comment: Una opción sería recibir el nombre del sp, y las columnas y valores por arreglos. De esta forma, recorrerías dichos arreglos en un loop y utilizas AddWithValue dentro de ese ciclo para ir agregando las columnas y valores correspondientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar la funcion AddRange para agregar una lista de SqlParameter así:

```
 public DataTable getSociosPorNombre(string storedProcedure,SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            cnn.ConnectionString = string_conexion;
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
            tabla.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            return tabla;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EXPLOTO EL HELPER", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection(cnn);
        }
    }
```

y podrías consumirlo de multiples formas, aquí existe una forma:

```
List<SqlParameter> listaParametros = new List<SqlParameter>();
        
        var param1 = new SqlParameter("parametro1", "valor1");
        param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        listaParametros.Add(param1);

        var param2 = new SqlParameter("parametro2", 255);
        param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        listaParametros.Add(param2);

        var param3 = new SqlParameter("parametro3", DateTime.Now);
        param3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
        listaParametros.Add(param3);


        var resultado =  getSociosPorNombre("miStoreProcedure", listaParametros.ToArray());
```

Comment: Una consulta, y como le paso los parametros desde el metodo que llama a este??? Hace falta aclarar en que columna va cada parametro???

Comment: Te añadí un ejemplo de como consumirlo, existen múltiples formas, saludos!.

Comment: Para que sea un poco más genérico el método, se pueden pasar los parámetros como un IEnunerable<SqlParameter> en lugar de SqlParameter[]